# Output custom field value

Tags: custom-field

I am reading wp codex about outputing custom field value.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

From that link, It shows how to output all custom fields associated with specific post

How can I take only specific custom fields value?

For example I added custom field name "SkypeID". In each post, skype ID can be anyone's skype ID

I want to be able to get the value of skype ID and output it on my function.php.

On my function, I want to be able to insert it so that I can produce a post/page and add skype call button that will invoke skype application and then call the user mentioned on the custom field.

Here is my skepe call button so far.

```
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_ValidSkypeID_1" style="margin:-32px 10em;">
<script type="text/javascript">
Skype.ui({
"name": "call",
"element": "SkypeButton_Call_ValidSkypeID_1",
"participants": ["ValidSkypeID"],
"imageSize": 32
});
</script>
</div>
```

this code works if I hard coded a valid skype ID in replacement to ValidSkypeID on line 1.

What I am trying to do now is to be able to insert skypeID on that location if there is a skype ID given in custom post.

Thanks

Comment: What is the custom fields name?

Comment: I believe OP mentioned that "SkypeID" is the custom field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you could try something like this to insert the Skype id by using [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta):

```
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Skype_ID', true) == true) {
  echo get_post_meta( $post_id, "Skype_ID", true );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but digging a little deeper into the codex you'll find methods for [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). So you could do something like this:

```
<?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); // or set this however you get the post id ?> 
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_<?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, "SkypeID", true ); ?>_1" style="margin:-32px 10em;">
<script type="text/javascript">
Skype.ui({
"name": "call",
"element": "SkypeButton_Call_ValidSkypeID_1",
"participants": ["ValidSkypeID"],
"imageSize": 32
});
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: This helps me arrive on the solution as well. Tried to give upvotes but it seems im not yet allowed. Your answer is very well appreciated. Thanks